# How do you join between Posts and Users in the Stack Overflow database?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump, sql

I'm trying to join between stackoverflow.com's dataset Posts and Users files and I'm having trouble. I want to add the user profile of the question poster to a Post.

Do I use User.AccountId or User.Id? Do I use Posts.OwnerUserId? Neither seems to work. I get no hits. I'm using the 2019-08-05 dataset. The semantics are never explained anywhere. I think AccountId is the global user ID and the UserId is the per-site ID. But still I get no hits.

Comment: Related: *[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677)* and *[Tutorial - Getting Started with Writing Queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use Users.ID and join with the Posts.OwnerUserId.

The Users.AccountId references the Global Network Account and can be used to link Users across databases/sites.

Here is an example query on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1147837) for the Stack Overflow database.

```
select title
     , owneruserid
     , tags
     , Posts.creationdate
     , Users.Displayname
     , Users.Reputation
from Posts
inner join Users on Users.Id = Posts.OwnerUserId
where Users.Id = 13969
and Posts.PostTypeId = 1
```

Here is what the result looks like:

[image]

This is kind of underdocumented in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) but the second answer from [leerssej](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326361/158100) has an ERD where the relation is made clear:

[image]

I've highlighted the relation with a red free hand circle (that circle turned out rather flat)

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.